# Show div upon submit

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am wanting to show a div (depending on the the value input) but I am seeing no errors in the console to point me in the right direction but there is something wrong with my code:

```
<style type="text/css">

#outputOne{display: none;}
#outputTwo{display: none;}
#outputThree{display: none;}

</style>

</head>

<body>


<form method="POST" onsubmit="return showResults()">

    <input type="text" id="valueOne" /><br />
    <input type="text" id="valueTwo" /><br />
    <input type="text" id="valueThree" /><br />
    <input type="submit" id="submit" />

</form>

    <div id="outputOne">Value One</div>
    <div id="outputTwo">Value Two</div>
    <div id="outputThree">Value Three</div>


<script>

function showResults(){

    if(value <= 100){
    document.getElementById('outputOne').style.display = "block";
    return true;
    } if(value > 500){
    document.getElementById('outputTwo').style.display = "block";
    return true;
    }if(value > 10000){
    document.getElementById('outputThree').style.display = "block";
    return true;
    }
}

</script>
```

Comment: Where is the `value` defined ?

Comment: form is going to submit ...too late to change the UI unless you use ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so there are a few problems:

You never define `value` inside that function... you need to do that. Second, a form submission will refresh the page, undoing any DOM changes you did. This can be fixed by changing it to a button which calls your function. Here's an updated version of your code that works:

```
<style type="text/css">

.hide{display: none;}
.show{display: block;}
.submit{height:20px; width: 100px;}

</style>

</head>

<body>

    <input type="text" id="valueOne" /><br />
    <input type="text" id="valueTwo" /><br />
    <input type="text" id="valueThree" /><br />
    <button id="submit" class="submit" onClick="showResults()"></button>

    <div id="outputOne" class="hide" >Value One</div>
    <div id="outputTwo" class="hide" >Value Two</div>
    <div id="outputThree" class="hide" >Value Three</div>

<script>

function showResults(){

    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('valueOne').value) + parseInt(document.getElementById('valueTwo').value) + parseInt(document.getElementById('valueThree').value);

    if(value <= 100){
        document.getElementById('outputOne').className = "show";
    }  else {
        document.getElementById('outputOne').className = "hide";
    }
    if(value > 500){
        document.getElementById('outputTwo').className = "show";
    } else {
        document.getElementById('outputTwo').className = "hide";
    }
    if(value > 10000){
        document.getElementById('outputThree').className = "show";
    } else {
        document.getElementById('outputThree').className = "hide";
    }
}

</script>
```

I've also switched the css to use classes, which is a bit more flexible and better practice.

Credit to Zakaria Acharki and mohsin azeem for spotting the `form` error causing a refresh, and to the always-helpful charlietfl for that and for pointing out my own silly error for the `submit` button.

Comment: ummm ... it's in the submit handler

Comment: Ah Charlie, always there to call me out on my mistakes just before I see them myself :p I've just fixed that haha!

Comment: So that make sense now because I hadn't declared `value` so how would I bind the other boxes together to add up the values? Any pointers would be great (JS is not my strong skill)

Comment: @millerbr - that's ever kind of you and it makes perfect sense what is happening here, however, it still fails to show any of the divs?

Comment: @Dan because the form will submit which reloads the page

Comment: @charlietfl so how would I overcome this hurdle?

Comment: Yep, charlie has nailed it - do you require a form for a specific reason?

Comment: @Dan you can't unless you change to using ajax to submit form

Comment: @millerbr not really,but basically its for a user to enter 3 values and it will show which package is their best option depending on the information provided

Comment: What I mean is, will it be sending data to a server, or is it all handled by the page?

Comment: Oh sorry no its not being stored its purely just an output so not being sent anywhere or being stored.

Comment: @dan you need to google for `how to submit form using ajax `

Comment: @Dan Ok I've updated my answer and tested it myself, should be working now - this is assuming it *doesn't* make a network request

Comment: @millerbris it easy to make it hide the other div, so if you output valueOne then resubmi with altering the values and then get valueTwo but it dosnt hide vaueOne

Comment: Yep, can be done by adding an `else` to the `if` statements. I've updated it again.

Comment: Thank you so much - I have understood what has been done here. I wasn't a million miles away but I really appreciate the time

Comment: Not a problem at all, we all start somewhere and sometimes the simplest things cause the biggest problems!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see something you should prevent submit by returning false instead of true because now the form will be submited in all the cases and you will never see the div shown since the page will be refreshed.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define `value` variable
And then return false on every if so that `div` will show on `submit` otherwise page will refresh and all default setting will be shown

Answer (score 0):

Try substituting `oninput` event for `onsubmit` event

```html
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    #outputOne {
      display: none;
    }
    #outputTwo {
      display: none;
    }
    #outputThree {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    
    function showResults() {
      var value = this.value;
      
      console.log(value);
      if (value <= 100) {
        divs[0].style.display = "block";
        divs[1].style.display = divs[2].style.display = "none";
      }
      if (value > 500) {
        divs[1].style.display = "block";
        divs[0].style.display = divs[2].style.display = "none";
      }
      if (value > 10000) {
        divs[2].style.display = "block";
        divs[0].style.display = divs[1].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
    window.onload = function() {
      divs = document.querySelectorAll("div[id^=output]");
      Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.forms[0].querySelectorAll("input")
      , function(el) {
        el.setAttribute("placeholder", "enter a number");
        el.oninput = showResults;
      });
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>


  <form method="POST">

    <input type="text" id="valueOne" />
    <br />
    <input type="text" id="valueTwo" />
    <br />
    <input type="text" id="valueThree" />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" id="submit" disabled />

  </form>

  <div id="outputOne">Value One</div>
  <div id="outputTwo">Value Two</div>
  <div id="outputThree">Value Three</div>
</body>
```

Comment: How do you get the above to hide a div if another one is called? So if you return valueOne then change the values to get valueTwo but then hide valueOne again?

Comment: @Dan _"How do you get the above to hide a div if another one is called? So if you return valueOne then change the values to get valueTwo but then hide valueOne again?"_ See updated post